# письмо не проходит спам фильтр

Tags: email, php, sendmail

Отправляю письмо через функцию mail. Приходит на gmail без проблем. А вот на остальные почтовики(mail, yandex) приходит но не проходит спам проверку. Вот тело письма с gmail:

```
Delivered-To: admin@xxxxx.ruReceived: by 10.229.186.6 with SMTP id cq6csp121603qcb;        Fri, 25 May 2012 03:20:45 -0700 (PDT)Received: by 10.112.51.228 with SMTP id n4mr1307785lbo.35.1337941244855;        Fri, 25 May 2012 03:20:44 -0700 (PDT)Return-Path: <www@server2.xxxxx.ru>Received: from server2.xxxxx.ru (server2.xxxxx.ru. [90.156.236.207])        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id b1si4473422lbg.40.2012.05.25.03.20.44        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);        Fri, 25 May 2012 03:20:44 -0700 (PDT)Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of www@server2.xxxxx.ru designates 90.156.236.207 as permitted sender) client-ip=90.156.236.207;Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of www@server2.xxxxx.ru designates 90.156.236.207 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=www@server2.xxxxx.ruReceived: from server2.xxxxx.ru (localhost [127.0.0.1])    by server2.xxxxx.ru (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id q4PAKhXJ025172    for <admin@xxxxx.ru>; Fri, 25 May 2012 10:20:43 GMT    (envelope-from www@server2.xxxxx.ru)Received: (from www@localhost)    by server2.xxxxx.ru (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id q4PAKh7B025171;    Fri, 25 May 2012 10:20:43 GMT    (envelope-from www)Date: Fri, 25 May 2012 10:20:43 GMTFrom: World Wide Web Owner <www@server2.xxxxx.ru>Message-Id: <201205251020.q4PAKh7B025171@server2.xxxxx.ru>To: admin@xxxxx.ruSubject: subjqwweee
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть в том, что спам фильтры не пускают пользователя www, попробуйте от другого имени

Comment: Соглашусь сделай пользователя нормально, и проверь, и иногда саппорт мейла реально не пропускает письма, но если им написать то они с радостью ответят и разблокируют твоего www@**** и все будет ок.

Comment: Поменял, доходит везде кроме mail.ru. На мэйле пиешт про ошибку протокола в логах.